# how to return a require call from macro in scala.js

Tags: scala, macros, scala.js

**Problem :** want to return () => require(path) from macro

```
def gql(args: js.Any*): js.Function0[js.Any] = macro rqlMacroImpl
//impl
val generatedFilePath = ...
   c.Expr[js.Function0[js.Any]](q"""
        {
           import scala.scalajs.js
                      import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSImport

            val func:js.Function0[js.Any] = () => require($generatedFilePath)// I want to return require(...)
            func
        }
     """)
```

**Tried So far**

```
//impl
    val generatedFilePath = ...
       c.Expr[js.Function0[js.Any]](q"""
            {
               import scala.scalajs.js
                          import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSImport
                @js.native
                @JSImport($generatedFilePath,JSImport.Default)
                object GQlImport extends js.Object
                val func:js.Function0[js.Any] = () => GQlImport
                func
            }
         """)
```

Failed with `Local native object/classes not allowed`

**Workaround :**

use `js.Dynamic.global.require(path)` and in sbt task replace `$g.require(` to `require(`

**any better options .. ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, because `@JSImport`s must be top-level, and macros can only be called in places which are not top-level.

The reason that `@JSImport` must be top-level is that it does *not* semantically correspond to `require`. Instead, it corresponds to `import` in ES2015. They *desugar* into `require` when targeting CommonJS modules, but that is a special case. Dynamic uses of `require` cannot be written in terms of `import` in ES2015, and therefore not in terms of `@JSImport` either.

Now the reason you have to tweak `$g.require` into `require` is another issue. It used to be the case that this was simply Node.js hijacking JavaScript in a non-spec-compliant way, and Scala.js would not allow you to access it. Now it turns out that ES2015 kind of makes that special `require` thing valid-ish, so eventually you'll be able to access it natively in Scala.js, through https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2800